Is there a better method than nested if/then to evaluate if cells in one set of columns has data, and then populate a different set of columns
I have a spreadsheet of products with all of their specifications. One group of columns indicate which certifications the products have, by putting an X, or "yes", or any character in the cell. (Columns A-D in the screenshot)
Using the screenshot as the example, what I would like to do is have another set of columns (E-H) that refer to columns A-D and populate the applicable certification image paths, filling them in from the left. So there should never be a gap.
For the screenshot, I entered the E-H cells manually just to show the desired outcome. I also shorted the text so the image wouldn't be super wide. An image path would be like "/volume/marketing/certs/UL.png".
I've got the first column to work using:
=IF(ISBLANK(A10),(IF(ISBLANK(B10),(IF(ISBLANK(C10),(IF(ISBLANK(D10),"","UL-C")),"ESTAR")),"EMF")),"UL")
I've been trying nested IF and ISBLANK formulas for the F-H columns, but it's clear that it'll be a long formula, so I wanted to see if there was an easier way before I continue with the nested IF/ISBLANK method.
Thanks!


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.


use REPT to map certifications

REPT(certs, has_cert), with has_cert = 1 for non-empty


use TOROW to 'compress' values to the left

define a table to hold the image paths - here for example 'imgPath`

then XLOOKUP(certs_maped,imgPath[Cert], imgPath[Path])






Cert
Path




EMF
/volume/marketing/certs/EMF.png


ESTAR
/volume/marketing/certs/ESTAR.png


UL
/volume/marketing/certs/UL.png


UL-C
/volume/marketing/certs/UL-C.png



=LET(certs, A1:D1, has_cert, --(A2:D8 <> ""),
    certs_maped, IF(has_cert, REPT(certs, has_cert), NA()),
    img_paths, XLOOKUP(certs_maped,imgPath[Cert], imgPath[Path]),
    acc_left, REDUCE(
        "Collect to left",
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(img_paths)),
        LAMBDA(acc,r, VSTACK(acc, IFERROR(TOROW(INDEX(img_paths, r, ), 2), "")))
    ),
    IFNA(DROP(acc_left, 1), "")
)



Thank you nkalvi. I tried the formula out and it worked well, except when I had a row where the product did not have any certifications, therefore nothing checked. When that happened, all of the cert img columns went blank and I got #CALC! in cell E2.

That works, no more CALC error. Thank you. I can work with this, but I have a follow up question that's just for curiosity. Would there be a way to code the image paths into the formula rather than building them based on the header rows of A-D? If this is too complicated for friendly help, then no worries; your formula is already the solution I need.

@SeanLarkin, I might have misunderstood your question, so please pardon me. Here’s ref to the previous answer https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4

To be fair, I may not have asked it correctly. lol. This may be a better way to ask:
Let's say I have no control over the cert image names or locations, so instead of them all having the same location and file extension, I had them in various folders, and in different file types.
So instead of:
/volume/marketing/certs/UL.png
/volume/marketing/certs/EMF.png
I had:
/volume/engineering/icons/ul-icon3.eps
/volume/common/engineers/mdavid/logos/EMF/emf.jpg
Your solution uses the header row to build the image path, but I'm wondering if there's a way to have the paths in the formula.

@SeanLarkin, I'd suggest maintaining image paths in a separate table. Please check the update to whether it helps. Please let me know if the performance is slow with your data.

I made the table, and then tried the revised formula but get the "There's a problem with this formula." error popup.  Once I click OK, this is the line of the formula that is showing: img_paths, XLOOKUP(certs_maped,imgPath[Cert], imgPath[Path]), and this section is highlighted:  imgPath[Cert].
.
I don't know if the highlight means anything, but thought it was worth mentioning. Maybe I'm setting up the cert and path table wrong. Does it need to be positioned in a certain spot in the spreadsheet?

@SeanLarkin, go to the table tab or Name Manager and make sure the table is named imgPath (default is Tablexx). Columns names need to be Cert and Path. Of course you can change any of this, but need to update the formula. Please let me know how it goes.

Happy to hear it - good luck with your task :)

This is what you need to do using FILTER() function:


=FILTER($A$1:$D$1,A2:D2<>"","")


Or, one single array formula:
=LET(
     a, A2:D8,
     IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,
     VSTACK(x,FILTER(A1:D1,INDEX(a,y,)<>"","")))),1),""))



Thank you Mayukh. I tried this in my sample file and it worked as described, although I get a #CALC! error if the row has now certifications checked off.

@SeanLarkin you will need to specify the last parameter of FILTER() function to avoid the #CALC! error: =FILTER($A$1:$D$1,A2:D2<>"","") please try now

Move Undesired Values to the Right Vol. 2

Your question is similar to Sort values and remove "0" with formula.

=LET(table,A1:D11,
    dd,DROP(table,1),
    d,IF(dd="","",TAKE(table,1)),
    rc,ROWS(d),
    cc,COLUMNS(d),
    WRAPROWS(SORTBY(TOCOL(d),TOCOL(SEQUENCE(rc,cc)
        +SEQUENCE(rc)*cc+(d="")*cc)),cc))



In cell E2 add:
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",$A$1)
For the first cells on row 2, in the rest of the data, the locked cell range in the last part of the IF formula would need to be changed to the appropriate value in cells A1 to D1. Flash Fill should be available if a Table, or drag down the formulas, from the bottom right corner.
